# How to Solve Glitch Preventing Me From Attacking!

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm a free to play player who's playing a Jedi Knight, 50th level.  On a mission called Firestorm, on the planet Corellia and at a place called Korvalus Towers I am unable to attack the Sith Stalkers in the game but am fine to attack other opponents.

When I click (any) attack button while focused on the Sith Stalker I get the message, "Out of range. Move closer."  This happens when I'm right up next to the Stalker.  Eventually I die of course and start back at the medical centre - and in this way cannot advance throught the game as this is my Primary (or is it called Class?) Mission.

Anyone else heard of this problem and any ideas how to fix it? 
(No customer service for FreetoPlay)

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game has a number of issues with NPCs being drawn at a different location from their "real" location, but it doesn't usually persist.  Have you restarted the game?  If you do and it doesn't help, try:

1. Exit the instance
2. Reset the quest
3. Exit the game
4. Start the launcher, log in, and do a Repair from the cog menu
5. Start the game and try again

If all that doesn't work, one other thing to try would be to attempt to discover the "real" location of the NPC.  When they are targeted you might be able to figure it out via the distance shown to them on the target bar.  You can also try using cleave/AoE abilities (non-targeted or ground-targeted) which will sometimes hit when you get this error.  As a Knight your best bets are Force Sweep and Cyclone Slash.

Comment: Thank-you for your suggestions.  I made it through although I could not do a repair from the cog menu - the possibility was 'grayed out'.  What did work was resetting the mission, and what I think mainly worked, was using Force Leap on the elusive Stalker to begin with.  Have to make sure your leap is going to land on them - once they had been targeted that way I could attack them further.  The one time I did not use Force Leap I could not attack the Stalker (my companion killed it).  So for anyone else with this problem I recommend Force Leap to pinpoint the problematic target first.